# Purchasing Reserved Instances to stop paying for existing Instances - AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-reserved-instances

I have a couple of instances(t2.micro & c5.2xlarge) that are running an application and they will be running 24/7 for the years to come. I am looking into buying reserved instances to save costs and have a question. If I purchase these instances, will they be automatically applied towards my existing instances?

Edit: my instances are regular on-demand not spot, sorry for the confusion.

Comment: Reservations only apply to on-demand instances, not spot. Spot is generally cheaper than reserved, but can be reclaimed by AWS if they need the capacity back.

Comment: Yes they will be automatically applied toward your existing instances, if you purchase the correct type that matches your existing instances. You should really look into AWS Compute Savings Plans as well, which are much more flexible.

Comment: You also might consider moving from T2 to T4g (if you can), since the costs are lower.